# how to convert an integer number to float (without any cast or union or memcpy)

Tags: c

i have the following code:

```
float a =   *((float *)(&OUT.ul[0]);
```

when value of `OUT.ul[0]` is `1073741824` the floating point is 4.

how does it calculated ? and how can i convert any integer number to float without this cast, only with bitwise operations?

Comment: The expression has undefined behaviour; don't use it. It is essentially reinterpreting memory in-place. You're not allowed to do that.

Comment: `float a = &OUT.ul[0] + 0.0;` perhaps? Assuming what you really want is the floating point representation of a pointer value, anyway... Otherwise, maybe the `&` doesn't belong there, but it's hard to tell without more context/information...

Comment: It is not an undefined behaviour. The memory would be interpreted according to [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: thanks for your comment. please tell me why the value 1073741824 in memory is 4 on float . how does it calculated?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: What makes this defined behavior in this special case (and what guarantees _that_ is how it's defined)? Usually, putting an object of one type into memory than reading that memory as if it contained an object of an unrelated type _is_ undefined, so claiming this has a specific defined behavior really should include a citation.

Comment: please see link :http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm - floating point numbers and the integer stored in memory

Comment: @EugeneSh.: it _is_ undefined behaviour. The compiler is allowed to miscompile that code, since that kind of pointer aliasing is not allowed by the standard. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strict-aliasing